# dropzone.js : click on thumbnail to show the original image?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm trying to use dropzone.js and I wouldlike to know what is the best way to add a link on the thumbnails to show the original image in a lightbox. I need to add a link around the data-dz-thumbnail with the success event from what I see.

To get something like this :

```
<a href="..." class="lightbox_class"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR..."></a>
```

instead of just

```
<img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...">
```

Thank you !

Comment: Are you sending the final url of the uploaded image to the success callback? or do you know where that image is going to land in advance? without this information is not possible to give you an accurate answer.